# Combine objects in an array with similar labels to a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to combine options values that have the same label value.

I need to extract the label from each {} section and all the options values for that label into a string for each {} section.

Desired output is

```
my Label 1
AA
BB
CC

Other Label
XX
YY
```

I have data like

```
let data = [
{
    label: "my Label 1",
    id: 1,
    options: [
      {
        id: 1,
        value: "AA"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        value: "BB"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        value: "CC"
      }
      ]
  },
  {
    label: "Other Label",
    id: 2,
    options: [
      {
        id: 3,
        value: "XX"
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        value: "ZZ"
      }
      ]
  }
]
```

What I have so far is

```
let combined = data.map(section => {
  let options = section.options.map(option => {
    return{
      sectionLabel: section.label,
      optionValue: option.value,
    }

  })  
  return options;
});
console.log(combined.flat());
```

Which gives the output

```
[ { sectionLabel: 'my Label 1', optionValue: 'AA' },
  { sectionLabel: 'my Label 1', optionValue: 'BB' },
  { sectionLabel: 'my Label 1', optionValue: 'CC' },
  { sectionLabel: 'Other Label', optionValue: 'XX' },
  { sectionLabel: 'Other Label', optionValue: 'ZZ' } ]
```

Comment: Why bother with creating a new structure? Just map directly to HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating an array of objects, concatenate to a string.

```js
let data = [{
    label: "my Label 1",
    id: 1,
    options: [{
        id: 1,
        value: "AA"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        value: "BB"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        value: "CC"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    label: "Other Label",
    id: 2,
    options: [{
        id: 3,
        value: "XX"
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        value: "ZZ"
      }
    ]
  }
]

let result = "";

data.forEach(({label, options}) => {
  result += label + '\n';
  options.forEach(({value}) => result += value + '\n');
  result += '\n';
});

console.log(result);
```